# Isotope Sort By HTML Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I want to sort the isotope results based on an html attribute:
HTML:

```
<div id="results">
    <div data-order="1">Test 1</div>
    <div data-order="2">Test 2</div>
    <div data-order="1">Test 2</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var container = jQuery('#results');
container.isotope({
    getSortData: {
        order: '[data-order] parseInt'
    },
    sortBy: ['order']
});
```

When I try this as noted from https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html#sortby it doesn't seem to be working for me. This is after I have set a filter.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, I needed to run the updateSortData function to apply my changes:

```
container.isotope('updateSortData').isotope();
```